How to Create a Binary Variable in R Based on a Specific Dictionary of Terms
I am looking to receive help on creating a binary variable in R based on whether a specific dictionary of terms appears within text data. I currently have a data frame, where one of those columns (text) contains different texts that I'm interested in analyzing. I would like to analyze whether texts surrounding animals appear in those columns (to be coded as 1), or if texts surrounding animals don't appear (coded as 0).
I already created an "animals" dictionary (animals_dict) (which contains three terms "cat, "dog", and "fish). Essentially, I'd like to create a new variable (data_zoo$animals), which indicates whether any of the texts contained mentions of the animals dictionary (1) or did not (0).
I've tried writing a code, but I keep getting an error. Here's what I have so far:
data_zoo <- mutate(data_zoo, data_zoo$animals = if_else(data_zoo$text=="animals_dict", 1, 0))

I would like help with getting the appropriate syntax to create this variable.

mutate(data_zoo, animals = +(text %in% animals_dict))

animals <- c("cat", "dog", "fish")

data_zoo <- data.frame(text = c("The dog barks", "Bored catfish", "Phish"))

data_zoo |>
  dplyr::mutate(animals = +stringr::str_detect(text, paste(animals, collapse = "|")))

           text animals
1 The dog barks       1
2 Bored catfish       1
3         Phish       0


Update, so I used the following:mutate(data_zoo, animals = if_else(text=="animals_dict", 1, 0)), but this code detects whether the column = "animals_dict" and isn't actually detecting whether the words from my dictionary appear anywhere in that column. any thoughts on revision?

data_zoo$text == "animals_dict" will be TRUE for any value of data_zoo$text that IS the text "animals_dict". You haven't shared what animals_dict looks like. I'm assuming it's a vector like my animals vector here. My code makes a lookup phrase that looks like cat|dog|fish and uses stringr::str_detect to test if any of those phrases are found in the text.
